# Ubuntu is still on rEFIt

Tags: uninstall, bootloader, format, refit

I just used a Ubuntu Live DVD to uninstall ubuntu from my mac by formatting both ext4 and linux-swap partitions to fat32 and then deleting them (so I could resize mac's partition later using apple's disk utility).

There is a problem now: Ubuntu is still appearing in rEFIt. Does that mean that the bootloader is still there somewhere? If so, where exactly is it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The boot loader could be either an EFI-mode boot loader on the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) or a BIOS-mode boot loader in the MBR or on a Linux partition (although if you've deleted *all* of the Linux partitions, a partition is an unlikely location). You can check for and deal with these possibilities as follows:

- You can mount the ESP in OS X by typing `sudo mkdir /Volumes/ESP; sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/ESP`. (This assumes the ESP is the first partition on your disk, as it is by default. If it's elsewhere, you'll need to adjust the command appropriately.) You can then search for a Linux boot loader under `/Volumes/ESP`. It would probably be in `/Volumes/ESP/EFI/ubuntu`. Delete the boot loader (a `.efi` file), and optionally its entire directory.
- You can erase the part of the MBR (or partition) that holds the BIOS boot code using `dd`. This is safest to do from Linux, so I recommend you boot a Linux live CD, then type `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=440 count=1`. ***Be very careful with this command!*** A mistake in the parameters can cause you to trash the disk. OS X is less suitable for this because, IIRC, it's impossible to write part of a sector with OS X's `dd`, and it's critical that you wipe just the first 440 bytes of the sector. (Sectors are normally 512 bytes in size.)

Alternatively, and a bit safer than the second option, you could upgrade from the abandoned rEFIt to its currently-maintained fork, [rEFInd.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) You can then edit its `refind.conf` file to achieve your ends. You can exclude directories from scans for EFI boot loaders with the `dont_scan_dirs` line, or remove all BIOS-mode boot loaders with the `scanfor` line (omit the `hdbios` option). The drawback to excluding BIOS-mode boot loaders with rEFInd is that if you're dual-booting with Windows, you'll probably lose the ability to boot it.